# How solve connect Mongodb cluster by mongo shell method

Tags: database, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a something problem. While I created Cluster on MongoDB Atlas then i have to connect to mongo shell. When i copy string on mongodb box and paste in my command line for connect mongoDB and my source but when i insert my password it show MongoNetworkError. What it's problem. Anyone can help me please!

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster1.xlavu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --apiVersion 1 --username BoroBlade

Enter password: ****************
Current Mongosh Log ID: 62f260cd5921dc2cd9212885
Connecting to: mongodb+srv://<credentials>@cluster1.xlavu.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.5.4
MongoNetworkError: connection 1 to 18.140.129.75:27017 closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the database `myFirstDatabase`. Mongosh is using that database for authentication. Most likely MongoDB is using the `admin` database for authentication.

Add the command line option:

```
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: I did it, but is not change.